# Why does the last part of sentence be led by "given ..."?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, american-english, british-english, sentence-patterns

Anyone can help to know why the last part of sentence below could be led by "given ...":

Japan's government wants nuclear power to comprise 20% to 22% of the overall energy mix by 2030, drawing criticism from campaigners who say nuclear plants will always pose a danger **given the country's vulnerability to large earthquakes and tsunamis**.

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked up a dictionary to see what "given" might mean in this context? What did you find?

Answer (score 2):

It is an idiomatic usage of “[given](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/given)” as a  (preposition):

> If you say given something, you mean taking that thing into account.
>
> - Given the uncertainty over Leigh's future I was left with little other choice.

(Collins Dictionary)